# Problemilla para enviar un telegrama Socket "Compuesto"

Tags: c#

Buenos dias StackOverflow!
Estoy inmerso en un problemilla que no se muy bien como resolver de manera "profesional" sin hacer mucho codigo y liarme la cabeza.

Estoy mandando un telegrama a un equipo mediante socket TCP, hago lo siguiente;

```
    byte [] mensaje = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txtASCII.Text);
    int bytesSent = envio.Send(mensaje);
```

El objeto "envio" es instanciado de la clase socket y me funciona perfectamente pero ademas de esto necesito hacer otra cosa, necesito mandar en el telegrama cualquiera de los primeros 31 caracteres de control del codigo ascii, es decir, necesito enviar de alguna manera una cadena compuesta de letras ascii normales y ademas concatenar caracteres de control y que el equipo se entere, el problema es que debo hacerlo de manera que el usuario pueda meter la cadena de manera coherente (para el).

Un ejemplo;
Si mando una cadena normal sin caracteres de control seria lo siguiente;
123ABC, que en decimal seria (49 50 51 65 66 67)

Con esto no hay problema porque la cadena la convierto directamente...

Pero si por ejemplo el usuario quiere enviar un retorno de carro al final del telegrama lo escribiria de esta forma (por poner alguna coherente)
123ABC(CR), en realidad deberia mandar el codigo anterior mas el 13 que es el CR pero no puedo hacer la conversion directa ya que me convertiria lo que no quiero "(CR)"

No se si me he explicado bien...
¿Se os ocurre alguna manera de hacerlo de manera limpia?

P.D: Edito el mensaje para añadir... Lo interesante seria controlar en todo momento donde estan los caracteres de control, ya que es posible meter varios en un mismo telegrama;
123ABCD(CR)(LF), por ejemplo...

Muchas gracias

Comment: No estoy seguro de entenderte ... lo que quieres es ¿ añadir *bytes* arbitrarios en cualquier parte de los datos a enviar ?

Comment: Si, poder enviar los clasicos caracteres de control según el usuario necesite, el problema es que los introduzo en un textbox y en ese textbox hay caracteres que simplemente hay que enviarlos "tal cual" pero los de control tengo que "codificarlos" manualmente antes de enviarlos, en el ejemplo que ponia antes;
123ABC(CR)
El 123ABC Al enviarlo en decimal enviaría un 49 50 51 65 66 67.
En cambio el (CR) tengo que tratarlo de antemano y enviar solo un 13,  no un 28 43 52 29, que es lo que realmente vale ese (CR) traducido a pelo

Comment: y si haces Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txtASCII.Text)+(CR) concatenar despues del encoding??? o en el peor de los caso si tienes acceso de lado del receptor puedes recivir el dato y agregarle el CR